# dijit filteringselect focus

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have multiple FilteringSlect on my page except first one, rest are disabled. Upon selecting a value in first, 2nd filteringselect gets enabled and so on. I'm able to achieve this. When a user selects value in the first filteringselect and then press tab to go to the next fitleringselect, it gets enabled but user has to click the mouse on 2nd fitleringselect to enter a value. I have a jsfiddle link

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/qpue91L9/75/`
```

which demonstrates the problem. What I want is, as soon as user tabs from first filteringselect, next one should get enabled and without an extra click, user should be able to select a new value by typing inside the fitleringselect textbox.

Comment: Not seeing the problem here.  In your fiddle, after selecting something from the first dropdown, I tab to the second and can immediately start typing or using up/down arrow to scroll through selection (No clicking required).  What browser are you using?? I tried it in firefox and it worked.

Comment: @ GoinOff, this is how I'm doing. Place the mouse cursor on the first filteringselect and then type 'A'. Immediately, you will see all states starting with letter 'A' and by default 'Alabama' is highlighted and shown in the textbox. Now press tab and the control goes to next Filteringselect and you can't type anything unless you do a mouse click on that filteringselect.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it working [Working fiddle][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/qpue91L9/125/
```

Also as suggested, providing the complete working code

HTML Code

```
<input id="stateSelect">
<input id="stateSelect1">
<input id="stateSelect2">
```

JS Code

```
require([
        "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/on","dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/domReady!",'dijit/registry',"dijit/focus","dojo/dom"
    ], function(Memory, on,FilteringSelect,ready,registry,focusUtil,dom){
        var stateStore = new Memory({
            data: [
                {name:"Alabama", id:"AL", timeStamp:"1211753600"},
                {name:"Alaska", id:"AK", timeStamp:"1211753601"},
                {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS", timeStamp:"1211753602"},
                {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ", timeStamp:"1211753603"},
                {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR", timeStamp:"1211753604"},
                {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE", timeStamp:"1211753605"},
                {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP", timeStamp:"1211753606"},
                {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA", timeStamp:"1211753607"},
                {name:"California", id:"CA", timeStamp:"1211753608"},
                {name:"Colorado", id:"CO", timeStamp:"1211753609"},
                {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT", timeStamp:"1211753610"},
                {name:"Delaware", id:"DE", timeStamp:"1211753611"}
            ], idProperty: "timeStamp"
        });

        var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
            id: "stateSelect",
            store: stateStore,
             tabIndex: 1,
            searchAttr: "name",
            identifier: "timeStamp",

        }, "stateSelect").startup();
        var filteringSelect1 = new FilteringSelect({
            id: "stateSelect1",
            name: "state",
             tabIndex: 2,
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name",
            identifier: "timeStamp" ,
            disabled:true,
        }, "stateSelect1").startup();
        var filteringSelect2 = new FilteringSelect({
            id: "stateSelect2",
            name: "state",
             tabIndex: 3,
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name",
            identifier: "timeStamp",
            disabled:true,        
        }, "stateSelect2").startup();

        on(dijit.byId("stateSelect"),"KeyPress",function(evt){
        dijit.byId("stateSelect1").set("disabled",false);

        });
         on(dijit.byId("stateSelect"),"change",function(evt){
        dijit.byId("stateSelect1").set("disabled",false);
         dijit.byId("stateSelect1").focus();

        });
        on(dijit.byId("stateSelect1"),"KeyPress",function(evt){
        dijit.byId("stateSelect2").set("disabled",false);

        });
         on(dijit.byId("stateSelect1"),"change",function(evt){
        dijit.byId("stateSelect2").set("disabled",false);
         dijit.byId("stateSelect2").focus();

        });


    });
```

Comment: @litelite , thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer with working code.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your example and got it working somewhat....

[Update Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5p71en1k/6/)

Basically, I added this:

```
require([ "dijit/focus", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(focusUtil, dom){
    var domObj = dom.byId("stateSelect1");
    focusUtil.focus(domObj);
});
```

and also added `tabIndex` property to each select object.  The problem is it only works when you actually select an item from the list by clicking on it. If tab is used then it doesn't work.  You could probably use this example and trap the tab event to make it work the way you want it too.

Comment: @ GoinOff, let me try this in my project and let you know. Thanks again for your help.